# Changing displayed data based on a state of a variable in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

im doing this simple [excercise](https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/time-tracking-dashboard-UIQ7167Jw), and Im stuck on the JS part. I have a **timeframe** variable, and everytime you click one of the buttons (daily, weekly, monthly), timeframe changes it's value - and I want the displayed data to change with it. I have seen another solution to this problem, where on every button click the whole data is refetched, but I want data to be fetched only once, when the page loads - if that makes sense. Below is my code:

```
const title1 = document.getElementById("title-1");
const title2 = document.getElementById("title-2");
const title3 = document.getElementById("title-3");
const title4 = document.getElementById("title-4");
const title5 = document.getElementById("title-5");
const title6 = document.getElementById("title-6");

const time1 = document.getElementById("time-1");
const time2 = document.getElementById("time-2");
const time3 = document.getElementById("time-3");
const time4 = document.getElementById("time-4");
const time5 = document.getElementById("time-5");
const time6 = document.getElementById("time-6");

const last1 = document.getElementById("last-1");
const last2 = document.getElementById("last-2");
const last3 = document.getElementById("last-3");
const last4 = document.getElementById("last-4");
const last5 = document.getElementById("last-5");
const last6 = document.getElementById("last-6");

const daily = document.getElementById("daily");
const weekly = document.getElementById("weekly");
const monthly = document.getElementById("monthly");

let timeframe;

const timeframes = [
  { element: daily, name: "Daily" },
  { element: weekly, name: "Weekly" },
  { element: monthly, name: "Monthly" },
];

timeframes.forEach((item) => {
  item.element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    timeframe = item.name;
    checkTimeframe();
  });
});

const checkTimeframe = () => {
  if (timeframe === "Daily") {
    weekly.classList.remove("chosen");
    monthly.classList.remove("chosen");
    daily.classList.add("chosen");
    return;
  }
  if (timeframe === "Weekly") {
    daily.classList.remove("chosen");
    monthly.classList.remove("chosen");
    weekly.classList.add("chosen");
    return;
  }
  if (timeframe === "Monthly") {
    weekly.classList.remove("chosen");
    daily.classList.remove("chosen");
    monthly.classList.add("chosen");
    return;
  }
  console.log("wrong name");
};

async function load() {
  const json = await fetch("/data.json");
  const data = await json.json();
  console.log(data);

  timeframe = "Daily";
  checkTimeframe();

  const titlesFromDOM = [title1, title2, title3, title4, title5, title6];
  let titlesFromJSON = data.map((item) => item.title);

  const currentFromDOM = [time1, time2, time3, time4, time5, time6];
  const lastFromDOM = [last1, last2, last3, last4, last5, last6];

  for (let i = 0; i < titlesFromDOM.length; i++) {
    titlesFromDOM[i].textContent = titlesFromJSON[i];
  }

  // if timeframe daily:
  if (timeframe === "Daily") {
    for (let i = 0; i < currentFromDOM.length; i++) {
      currentFromDOM[i].textContent = data[i].timeframes.daily.current + "Hrs";
      lastFromDOM[i].textContent =
        "Last day - " + data[i].timeframes.daily.previous + "Hrs";
    }
  }

  // if timeframe weekly:
  if (timeframe === "Weekly") {
    for (let i = 0; i < currentFromDOM.length; i++) {
      currentFromDOM[i].textContent = data[i].timeframes.weekly.current + "Hrs";
      lastFromDOM[i].textContent =
        "Last week - " + data[i].timeframes.weekly.previous + "Hrs";
    }
  }

  // if timeframe monthly:
  if (timeframe === "Monthly") {
    for (let i = 0; i < currentFromDOM.length; i++) {
      currentFromDOM[i].textContent =
        data[i].timeframes.monthly.current + "Hrs";
      lastFromDOM[i].textContent =
        "Last month - " + data[i].timeframes.monthly.previous + "Hrs";
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", load);
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: do you have a sandbox example that can be tested against?

Answer (score 1):

Posting the html structure and data structure will help. However from the posted code. The first thing I would do is to retrieve the parent of the timeframe elements and apply the eventlistener there. The listener handler function will then use the event.target object to determine the clicked timeframe element [I imagine that the elements have a common parent]. I will draw a relationship between the display element and the data. Again if the display elements have a common parent I will use a querySelectorAll to retrieve them as a nodelist, updating the elements using the data based on the identified relationship and the clicked timeframe element.